# How to run c++ code from c++?

Tags: c++, reflection

If I have some c++ code as a string quantity (data) in a c++ program, can I execute the contents of that string?

As using the CodeDOM in C# or the eval function present in perl, python, etc..

Comment: This is a very strange question.

Comment: maybe you should add a little more detail about what you want answered?

Comment: This is either a really DUMB question or a funny joke.

Comment: i mean that u have a string and you can compile it, like CodeDom in C#

Comment: Not, dumb as such, just very, very naive.

Comment: Chad, people will take you more seriously if you take the time to spell out "you" and kin. Typing "u" make us feel like you're not putting any effort into your question, and nobody would want to answer that.

Answer (score 10):

**Short answer:** you can't.

**Slightly longer answer:** c++ has no reflection, and is generally compiled, so there so is no support for this kind of thing, and it can not be easily added..

**Work arounds:**

1. Use an embeddable dynamic language like [python|tcl|ruby|...] in concert with your c++ code. Now you need to have the dynamic language (rather then c++) in the data.
2. Use a c++ interpreter like [cint](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint) or ch. This binds you to the interpreter.
3. Use the system c++ compiler to construct a dynamic library from your code and link to it on the fly. Risky and system dependent.
4. Use a different language.

Answer (score 5):

No. As C++ is a static language, you can not dynamically eval arbitrary code.

You could interpret it or even compile and run it seperately as Keith suggested

Comment: This answer just doesn't make any sense. "You cannot dynamically eval" but "you could interpret" - what's that supposed to mean? Oh, and of course you can write an evaluator for C++ expressions, or even a full-fledged C++ interpreter... it's just there's no full-featured premade one out there.

Answer (score 3):

if you mean compile C++ code on the fly and run it?  sure if you have a compiler available to you

Comment: i mean that u have a string and you can compile it, like CodeDom in C#

Comment: This is the closest I can imagine doing, compiling the code and dynamically linking the new DLL. It's hardly very safe though.

Comment: C++ has no in-built reflective capabilities like C#, so it's going to be very difficult no matter what.

Comment: I don't see what "reflective capabilities" have to do with it at all. Ideally, you'd take C++ code, compile it in-memory, and get a pointer to its `main` (or any other exported symbol of your choice). Tiny C Compiler does precisely that for C. It's certainly doable for C++, just complicated, and no-one bothered so far. I guess if you really try hard, you could extract everything necessary out of g++ (except for the command line binary), and use that.

Comment: @Pavel - the reflection is relevant in terms of accessing variables from the main app. Of course, having to explicitly specify what is accessible and how is a *very* good idea, but you have to admit (and already did) - it's not exactly trivial to do as with some scripting language please-exploit-this-gaping-security-hole solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Non of the mainstream C++ implementations have that feature, as C++ is not reflective.

However, take a look at Ch, it might be what you are looking for:

http://www.softintegration.com/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch_interpreter

You can embed Ch interpreter into your C++ application and run dynamic C++ code inside it.

Comment: If you don't have to embed C++, I would recommend that you consider embedding lua or python - both are very easy to integrate with C++.

Answer (score 2):

C++ cannot do this - the compiled program has no knowledge of the source language syntax, identifier names etc.

Even if you go to the effort of writing the string out to a file, calling a c++ compiler to generate a dynamic library and loading and calling it, that call won't have any knowledge of your program - it won't be able to reference your variables etc.

The most common reason to want to do this is to be able to evaluate expressions from within strings. Writing the code to do this from scratch is definitely non-trivial, but depending on your specific requirements, you should be able to find a library or embeddable scripting language to do roughly what you need.

After a quick Google, I found [this](http://www.parsifalsoft.com/examples/evalexpression/index.html) - C rather than C++, and I don't know how good it is. It's written as a demo of a parser generator that I haven't heard of. You might find alternatives as demos of better known parser generators such as yacc, bison, yacc++ or antlr.